# Improve Django View with Methods

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to improve my Django web application and mainly project scripts.
I'm using many times the same Python code and I would like to simplify my `views.py` file.

For example, I have several times this part :

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = FormBase(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid() :
        post = form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ReverseTemplate', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

else :
    form = FormBase()
    form.fields['Utilisateur'].initial = request.user.last_name + " " + request.user.first_name
```

So, instead of copy/past this part in my different view function, I would like to set :

```
def DjangoFormID(request, FormBase, ReverseTemplate) :

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = FormBase(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid() :
            post = form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ReverseTemplate', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else :
        form = FormBase()
        form.fields['Utilisateur'].initial = request.user.last_name + " " + request.user.first_name
```

And call this function in my view :

```
DjangoFormID(request, IndividuFormulaire, IndividuResume)
```

I would like to know if my process is fine ? Is it a better way to programming rather than what I've done ?

Then, I'm getting this error : `name 'IndividuResume' is not defined`

How I could write my Django template inside my method ?

Thank you

Comment: did you try [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) ?

Comment: @BearBrown I have never used `Generic editing views` :/ Do you think that my process is false ? I would like to simplify my script and call functions when it's possible because I have many times the same script part in my view.

Comment: i think [class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/) best way to create django project.

Comment: @BearBrown You're right ! I will learn more about this Django part and maybe take time to modify my project. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is because `'IndividuResume'` should be a string, not a variable name.

```
DjangoFormID(request, IndividuFormulaire, 'IndividuResume')
```

Inside your template, you should use the variable `ReverseTemplate`, not the hardcoded string `'ReverseTemplate'`

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(ReverseTemplate, kwargs={'id': post.id}))
```

The advantage of including the same boilerplate in each view is that it's very easy to follow what is going on. If you are worried about the repetition, I would consider looking at class based views, because they are designed for this kind of use case. I would avoid defining your own `DjangoFormID` -- if I was new to your project I would not know what `DjangoFormID(request, IndividuFormulaire, 'IndividuResume')` did, so it would slow me down.

If you do stick with your `DjangoFormID` method then here's a couple of recommendations:

- Make sure it always returns a response. At the moment, it returns a redirect response for a valid form, and `None` the rest of the time, which is going to cause problems.
- when I see `DjangoFormID` I assume it's a class, not a function. Rename it to `django_form_id`.

Comment: Ok I see now where I made a mistake. Before to learn more about class based views, I just have a little question. In my function `DjangoFormID` I have a variable `form`. But I defined `form` in my views context and not in `DjangoFormID` so I get this issue : `name form is not defined`

Comment: Ok I will look all your recommendations ! I'm pretty new with Django (and programming) and some advices from people like you are very very interesting ! Thank you :)